# Split word in Prolog

Tags: string, split, prolog, character

I am trying to split a word in characters in Prolog without using list. Is it possible? All the results from searches that I already saw use lists.

Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with lists?  Kind of a fundamental thing in Prolog.

Comment: @Vasileios without example like what ?

Comment: I don't have the permission to use lists. Right! An example is: given as input the word "baa" to have output " "baa" consists of 'b', 'a', 'a' ".

Comment: If you split a word into characters, how would you want to contain the individual characters in a variable if not using a list? Or do you want to contain them in a variable? This is unclear. Please show an example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible without using using a list...I can't think of any library functions that could help that don't use a list themselves.